# How do I garbage collect in smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk

In my image I have a large number of instances of a certain object I want to make sure they are needed. How can I do a global garbage collect?

Answer (score 3):

Run the following in a workspace:
    System globalGarbageCollect

Comment: In [tag:Squeak] and [tag:Pharo] Smalltalk use `Smalltalk garbageCollect` or `Smalltalk garbageCollectMost`

Answer (score 1):

If you're more paranoid about control over objects, you can do something like this (from Pharo):

```
(PackageInfo named: 'YourPackageName') classes do:[:each |

    each allInstances do: 
        [:e | e breakDependents. 
                          e releaseActionMap. 
                          e isMorph ifTrue: [ e abandon]
                    ]
    ].
```

You can then garbagecollect as already mentuoned.
This is EXTREME and mostly almost always unnecessary.